# how to read from mongodb which version is before version 2.6 in spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, etl

The official [spark-mongodb-connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) only support mongodb version afer 2.6, but our production environment using mongodb v2.4. Can anyone suggest me a reasonable solution for etl? thanks!

Comment: MongoDB 2.4 reached end of life in March, 2016 and MongoDB 2.6 EOL'd in October, 2016. The most reasonable solution would be to upgrade your production environment to a supported release of MongoDB server (ideally 3.2 or newer, as there have been significant improvements such as the `$sample` operator). You could try using the Spark Connector with MongoDB 2.4, but this isn't tested or officially supported. Have you tried the Spark Connector with 2.4, and if so are there any specific error messages?

Comment: @Stennie Using spark connector with 2.4,  throw this error message "" Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error -1: 'unrecognized field "allowDiskUse' on server **** The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "unrecognized field \"allowDiskUse" } "". Should I need to rewrite source code for fixing this bug?

Comment: The `allowDiskUse` option (which allows writing to temporary files) was added in MongoDB 2.6. As noted in my earlier comment, the reasonable (and recommendable) approach would be to upgrade to a newer & supported version of MongoDB.